# MySQL Subquery: multiple queries on same table optimization

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a database table that I would like to search twice, the first time to establish a list of entries meeting a certain criteria and then use that list to limit my second one showing ALL entries having the matching 'name'

The following query does what I want, but it takes forever is there an easy alternative that runs more optimally?

```
SELECT * FROM voting WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM voting WHERE yob=15)
```

I also tried,

```
SELECT * FROM voting WHERE name = (SELECT name FROM voting WHERE yob=15)
```

this didn't work at all, but I think shows the logic of what I'm wanting to do.  Thanks.

Comment: Why the need to search it twice? Why would `SELECT * from voting WHERE yob = 15` not suffice?

Comment: Good question.  The idea is that I have multiple rows with the same name and each of those rows has a different yob, some yobs are 15 some are not.  I want to ultimately show ALL ROWS, regardless of YOB, but only for those names that have at least one yob of 15.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Great explanation, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to using `exists`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM voting v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM voting v2 WHERE v2.name = v.name AND yob = 15);
```

For this query, you want an index on `voting(name, yob)`.

Comment: Indexing was indeed the solution! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also, but should have index.

```
SELECT a.* FROM voting a JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM voting WHERE yob=15) AS b
WHERE a.name = b.name;
```

If you have millions of data in your table then this also may stuck for sometime.